# Выравнивание текста по центру CSS

Tags: html, css, center

Есть Owl Карусель, в которой нужно центрировать h2, p и a. Пишу text-align: center; - не работает. Как только не пробовал, всё равно тест не выравнивается. Возможно что-то мешает. Буду благодарен за помощь!
HTML:

```
   <div class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
    <div class="item">
      <h2>Надпись 1</h2>
      <p>Описание первого слайда карусели</p>
      <a href="#">Читать дальше</a>
      <img src="{% static 'image\default_news_carousel.jpg' %}">
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <h2>Надпись 2</h2>
      <p>Описание второго слайда карусели</p>
      <a href="#">Читать дальше</a>
      <img src="{% static 'image\default_news_carousel.jpg' %}">
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <h2>Надпись 3</h2>
      <p>Описание третьего слайда карусели</p>
      <a href="#">Читать дальше</a>
      <img src="{% static 'image\default_news_carousel.jpg' %}">
    </div>
   </div>
```

CSS:

```
.owl-carousel {
  position: relative;
}

.owl-nav {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  top: 100px;
}

.owl-prev {
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  height: 100px;
  width: 50px;
}

.owl-next {
  right: 0;
  position: absolute;
  height: 100px;
  width: 50px;
}

.owl-dots {
  position: absolute;
  left: 48%;
  top: 270px;
}

.item {
  height: 300px;
}

.item h2, p, a {
  position: absolute;
}

.item h2 {
  top: 30%;
  font-size: 48px;
  color: #fafafa;
}
```

Comment: А это что `.item h2, p, a {position: absolute;}`?

Comment: @Sevastopol' Указал, элементы понесло куда-то. Когда уменьшаешь страницу элементы вообще пропадают. И плюс я почему-то не могу указывать значения для h2, p, и а вместе, приходится каждому элементу писать отдельно, иначе съезжают все элементы сайта, даже те, которые не относятся к карусели. Можно ли сделать как-то через text-align?

Comment: @Andrey Fedorov Без этого элементы не накладываются поверх слайда (изображения) карусели

Comment: в таком случае они не могут быть выровнены, так как у них нет родителя, относительно которого возможно было бы выравнивание с помощью `text-align: center`.

Comment: @Andrey Fedorov а они же находятся в div или это не то? Все 3 элемента обёрнуты в div с классом item. Может в его свойства что-либо прописать?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/position

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вариант добавить `left: 50%; transform: translateX(-50%);` для `.item h2, p, a`. Пример:

```css
.item h2,
p,
a {
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}

.owl-carousel {
  position: relative;
}

.owl-nav {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  top: 100px;
}

.owl-prev {
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  height: 100px;
  width: 50px;
}

.owl-next {
  right: 0;
  position: absolute;
  height: 100px;
  width: 50px;
}

.owl-dots {
  position: absolute;
  left: 48%;
  top: 270px;
}

.item {
  height: 300px;
}

.item h2,
p,
a {
  position: absolute;
}

.item h2 {
  top: 30%;
  font-size: 48px;
  /*color: #fafafa;*/
}
```

```html
<div class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
  <div class="item">
    <h2>Надпись 1</h2>
    <p>Описание первого слайда карусели</p>
    <a href="#">Читать дальше</a>
    <img src="{% static 'image\default_news_carousel.jpg' %}">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <h2>Надпись 2</h2>
    <p>Описание второго слайда карусели</p>
    <a href="#">Читать дальше</a>
    <img src="{% static 'image\default_news_carousel.jpg' %}">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <h2>Надпись 3</h2>
    <p>Описание третьего слайда карусели</p>
    <a href="#">Читать дальше</a>
    <img src="{% static 'image\default_news_carousel.jpg' %}">
  </div>
</div>
```

Если через `text-align: center;`, то для `.item h2, p, a` добавить `left: 0; right: 0; text-align: center;`. Пример:

```css
.owl-carousel {
  position: relative;
}

.owl-nav {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  top: 100px;
}

.owl-prev {
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  height: 100px;
  width: 50px;
}

.owl-next {
  right: 0;
  position: absolute;
  height: 100px;
  width: 50px;
}

.owl-dots {
  position: absolute;
  left: 48%;
  top: 270px;
}

.item {
  height: 300px;
}

.item h2,
p,
a {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

.item h2 {
  top: 30%;
  font-size: 48px;
  /*color: #fafafa;*/
}
```

```html
<div class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
  <div class="item">
    <h2>Надпись 1</h2>
    <p>Описание первого слайда карусели</p>
    <a href="#">Читать дальше</a>
    <img src="{% static 'image\default_news_carousel.jpg' %}">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <h2>Надпись 2</h2>
    <p>Описание второго слайда карусели</p>
    <a href="#">Читать дальше</a>
    <img src="{% static 'image\default_news_carousel.jpg' %}">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <h2>Надпись 3</h2>
    <p>Описание третьего слайда карусели</p>
    <a href="#">Читать дальше</a>
    <img src="{% static 'image\default_news_carousel.jpg' %}">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Возможно я что-то неправильно делаю, но по центру оно не становится (правее центра прижато к верхнему краю). И опять же почему-то я не могу указать значения сразу к нескольким элементам потому-что тогда свойства применяются ко всему сайта. Спасибо

Comment: Спасибо, что пытались помочь, я сам не могу понять в чём дело то. Ещё и почему-то у меня текст абсолютно игнорирует параметр text-align: center; То есть даже если я каким-то образом сделаю, что бы он был по центру (например с помощью параметра left), всё равно при изменении размера страницы или количества символов текст будет съезжать.